# In .NET MAUI, how do I send a clicked object, within a list, and read it in another page?

Tags: c#, maui

As an overall example, consider the following classes:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
}
```

And this:

```
public class Bookshelf
{
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

If I populate my `Bookshelf` with 3 objects of type `Book`, and put the `Bookshelf` in a CollectionView, I could have some code in my Viewmodel, that handles the Click-event when a book is clicked in the CollectionView.

It could be something like:

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task BookClicked()
{
    try
    {
        var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Book", book }
        };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(BookPage)}", navigationParameter);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**This sends the object, Book, to my `BookPage`. But how do I retrieve the value of the clicked object in my `BookPage`, and display it on the page itself?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the navigation data using query property attributes.

Navigation data can be received by decorating the receiving class with a `QueryPropertyAttribute` for each string-based query parameter and object-based navigation parameter.

Please refer to the following code:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Bear), "Bear")]
public partial class BearDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    Animal bear;
    public Animal Bear
    {
        get => bear;
        set
        {
            bear = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public BearDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

For more information, please check the official document: [Process navigation data using query property attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-query-property-attributes).

Of course, you can also get navigation data using a single method.

For more information, please check document: [Process navigation data using a single method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-a-single-method).

Comment: This was what I've been looking for. Specifically, [this sample.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/Fundamentals/Shell)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the parameter to the command like this:

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task BookClicked(Book book)
{
    try
    {
        var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Book", book }
    };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(BookPage)}", navigationParameter);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And in your Collection use GestureRecognizers to get to your command:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Book">
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:TestViewModel}}, Path=BookClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Large"
                            Text="{Binding Title}"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Small"
                            Text="Author:"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontSize="Small"
                            Text="{Binding Author}"
                            TextColor="Black" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

To access your Book from the BookPage you load it from the BookPageViewModel and decorate the ViewModel with a QueryProperty:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Book), "Book")]
public partial class BookPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Book _book;

}
```